# How to change the default sort order in Windows Open window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sorting, usability

How to change the default sort order in Windows Open window?

Example: `Paint => File => Open => /* need to order by date by default */`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top-right of the Open menu you will see a button for
"Change your view" : [image].

Click it and choose the Details view, then click on the
"Date modified" column to sort by order descending.
A second click will sort by order ascending, etc.

Once you choose one file, it should remember this order for the
future.

Comment: On the top-left of the Open menu I don't see a button for "Change your view". Can you attack a screenshot please?

Comment: I meant "top-right", and the screenshot is already inside the answer.

Comment: On my Windows 10 there is this button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxKtu.png.

Comment: Explorer and Paint are tied together. However since the answer within Paint is working for you right now, I deleted my post.

Comment: @John Ok, no pb. _Explorer and Paint are tied together_: thanks for the info.

Comment: I have put my post back for the benefit of other who may need the information that Explorer and Paint file operations are tied together.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps have their own File Open browse setup. Your example is Microsoft Paint.

Paint uses the Windows Explorer default sort order to open Paint files.

Open Windows Explorer, open your main folder, sort it by Name, then View ribbon, Options, View in the Folder Options window and click on Apply to Folders.

Now Paint will open as you set it. That works here just as I posted above.

Many, but not all, apps sort File Open this way. Apps use Explorer not their own mechanism.

Any time you change Windows Explorer sort, Paint will change also. The sort order for Paint is not independent of the sort order for Windows Explorer:  Change one and it changes the other.

[image]

Comment: I did. Now Windows Explorer sorts the folder by date, but Paint keeps sorting the folder by name (instead of sorting by date). Why and how to fix?

Comment: Answer by user @harrymc solved the problem.

Comment: In the view above, click on Reset Folders, close out, restart, then open Explorer,  go to a top level folder, sort by date and then try Paint again. The two things (Explorer and Paint) are tied together